# "The contents of this iPad could not be read" - error when connecting 2020 iPad Pro (iPadOS 14.8) to M1 Max MBP (macOS 12.1)

Tags: ipad, ipados

As I can't update my iPad via its Settings ("An error occurred while checking for a software update"), I am trying to do so via Finder on my MBP. However, I'm stymied because of the error in subject. I've tried 2 cables, so I don't believe it's a problem with the cable - any ideas? I can't even back it up. What would cause such an error? How do I back it up if the contents can't be read? There are files on there I don't want to lose.

If the SSD is corrupt, what would have caused it? It's rarely taken out, has never been dropped, or subjected to rough handling, so I can't see what the issue would be.

Is there any way I can resolve this without restoring it? Are there any diagnostics I can run?

My Mac has no problem reading my older iPad Pro (2017).

If I look at 'USB' in SysInfo, I can see my iPad there, so the computer obviously knows it exists.

Thanks

Comment: How old is your last backup? How full is the iPad?

Comment: The iPad has around 450GB free. I don't know whether this was the right way to do it, but I managed to back it up and update it using iMazing (which had no problems reading, backing up and updating it). Interesting that a 3rd-party app was able to do what macOS wasn't. Technically, it's resolved but, also, technically, it isn't. I would really like to understand why Finder is unable to read it. As I say, it has no issues with my older iPad Pro (which has taken a fair bit more punishment than the 12.9" (including falling out of my bag off a train luggage rack!)). Thank you for your help.